# Why does the $\partial P/\partial y$ and $\partial Q/\partial x$ do not matter while calculating divergence?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-fields, divergence-operator

[Intuition of Divergence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKlpZ0UUJTQ&list=PLSQl0a2vh4HC5feHa6Rc5c0wbRTx56nF7&index=52)

Given a vector field $A=[P,Q]$, the divergence $\nabla.A = \partial P/\partial x + \partial Q/\partial y.$

Why do the change of $P$ in the $Y$ direction and the change of $Q$ in the $X$ direction *not affect* the divergence? Why is it not included in the formula? I get the visual reason (whatever comes in is pushed out with the same intensity so the density within the box is not disturbed) for a field like $[y,0]$ but I'm not able to justify it mathematically.
[image]

And even my visual reasoning fails for a field like $[x+y,0]$ where both  $\partial P/\partial y$ and  $\partial P/\partial x$ are non zero.

Comment: What is your definition of "divergence"?

Comment: @ancientmathematician 
A number that tells us by how much "things" tend to flow away from a given point. I understand it's very naive but this is how I've remembered it till now.

Comment: Yeah, but you are asking a precise mathematical question about a hand-waving concept, so it's hard to answer you. Perhaps if you resolve the flow in the $x$ and $y$ directions you can see that the total flow is just this linear combination of the two components?